# Whats going wrong with my code ? The global variable value changed while using semaphore

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, posix, semaphore

```
          #include<pthread.h>
          #include<stdio.h>
          #include<semaphore.h>
              void func();
              int a;
              int main()
              {  

                 pthread_t thread1;
                 sem_t semaphore1;
                 sem_init(&semaphore1,0,1);
                 pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,(void *)func,NULL);
                 sem_wait (&semaphore1);
                 a=62;
                 printf("%d",a); \\ as i found on google 
                 sleep(2);   \\ i believe a value should be sticked to 62
                 sleep(1);    \\ but output shows different why?
                 printf("%d",a);
                 sem_post(&semaphore1);
              } 
            void func()
             {  
              a=45;
              sleep(1);
              a=32;
              a=75;
           printf("hello");
             }
```

When i Googled it.I found sem_wait locks the global variable so that no other thread access the variable.

But when i tried these code the output is

```
           62 
           hello 
           75.
```

The a value got changed but note that the printf("%d",a) is under the sem_wait ,Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semaphores offer only advisory locking. They don't know about variables and such, they lock **regions of your code**. They don't enforce anything so you must call `wait` and `post` yourself.

Here is what `wait` and post really mean when used in your example.

```
sem_wait (&semaphore1); /* AKA "may I enter this region" */

sem_post(&semaphore1); /* AKA "I am done with this region. */
```

The way I see it, `main` asks for permission before entering. `func` doesn't ask for permission before modifying `a`.

So `func` should `wait` and `post`.

```
void func()
{
    sem_wait (&semaphore1);
    a=45;
    sleep(1);
    a=32;
    a=75;
    printf("hello");
    sem_post (&semaphore1);
}
```

Of course, for this `sempahore1` should be globally accessible.

Comment: What would be option you mean the mutex?

Comment: @niko Indeed you are using the semaphore like a mutex. But that's not the problem :)

Comment: its the lock() concept similar to C#